# RegExp to find the string inside first parentheses only?

Tags: javascript

For Example in the string:

```
create or replace procedure SYSPROC.Q2SPJ016(
p_SLNO in INTEGER,
p_HIRE_DATE in DATE,
p_BUSINESS_GROUP in VARCHAR(25)
)
```

Desired Output:

```
p_SLNO in INTEGER,
p_HIRE_DATE in DATE,
p_BUSINESS_GROUP in VARCHAR(25)
```

Comment: Probably better to use a SQL parser rather than rolling your own...

Comment: @loveToCode You can't right a regular exrpression to match this as it requires recursion. I have added a function that does this using regex and stack .accept it if it helps you solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shot Answer** : **Regex** alone can not solve this problem

Regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job because you are dealing with nested structures, i.e. recursion. You can use regular expressions and a stack to do this

Here is how you may do it

```js
//function that matches outer most paranthesis
function matchOuterBracket(str) {
  let re = /\(|\)/gi
  let stack = []
  let startI = -1,
    endI = -1
  while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    if (match[0] == '(') {
      stack.push(match.index)
    } else {
      startI = stack.pop()
    }
    if (stack.length == 0) {
      endI = match.index
      break
    }
  }
  if (startI == undefined ||
    startI == -1 ||
    endI == -1 ||
    endI == undefined) {
    return ""
  }
  return str.slice(startI +1 , endI)
}


//testing

var str = `create or replace procedure SYSPROC.Q2SPJ016(
p_SLNO in INTEGER,
p_HIRE_DATE in DATE,
p_BUSINESS_GROUP in VARCHAR(25)
)`
console.log(matchOuterBracket(str))
```